# lxc option "--" when calling lxc-start / lxc-create

Tags: command-line, containers, lxc, linux-containers

What is the significance of `--` in the command line of commands like  `lxc-create` or `lxc-start`.

I tried to use Google in order to get an answer but without success.

```
// Example 1
lxc-create -t download -n u1 -- -d ubuntu -r DISTRO-SHORT-CODENAME -a amd64

// Example 1
application="/root/app.out"
start="/root/lxc-app/lxc-start"
$start -n LXC_app -d -f /etc/lxc/lxc-app/lxc-app.conf -- $application &
```

Comment: See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the references provided in the comments, the "--" indicates the end of the options passed to the command. The following parameters/options will be eventually used by a sub-command called by the command.

In your example:

```
lxc-create -t download -n u1 -- -d ubuntu -r DISTRO-SHORT-CODENAME -a amd64
```

`lxc-create` command will interpret "-t download -n u1" and the remaining "-d ubuntu -r DISTRO-SHORT-CODENAME -a amd64" will be passed to the template script which will configure/populate the container.

In this specific example, the "-t download" makes `lxc-create` run a template script named something like "/usr/share/lxc/templates/lxc-download" to which it will pass "-d ubuntu -r DISTRO-SHORT-CODENAME -a amd64".

Comment: Thank you, your answer was more than enough.